# Enabling C compiler warnings in NetBeans 7

Tags: c, netbeans, compiler-construction, warnings

I started using NetBeans for programming in C so I installed Cygwin compiler and set up NetBeans to use it as compiler but when building the project it doesn't show any compiler warnings. I added -Wall and -pedantic options to project settings to use when compiling but while building the project it won't show more than line as as:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
```

and so on but no actual warnings. I was looking all over the settings and I couldn't find anything just yet.

I am kind of new at this so is there a way to do that?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`make` doesn't take `-Wall -pedantic` parameters. Those are compiler parameters, so you probably have to look inside the Makefile-Debug.mk file and add them there. It gets more difficult if this file is automatically generated. Then you have to look further in the NetBeans IDE. But I guess your parameters should already be inside the .mk file..

Comment: I'm not sure NetBeans used those parameters for make as I added them at Project Properties -> Build -> C Compiler -> Command Line Options and Additional Options so I figured gcc.exe uses these parameters.

Comment: @Martin: Yes you're right. But you ask in your question where the arguments are in the make line.. they don't show up there. You should have a look inside the .mk file.

Comment: Then I was misunderstood. I was looking for compiler warning output. Of course I can't be 100% sure whether I set parameters correctly but when I don't see the gcc compiler output with warnings I will never be  sure.